# What's the difference between std::wstring_convert and std::wbuffer_convert?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, character-encoding, c++11

There are two convenience interfaces declared in header file locale : `std::wstring_convert` and `std::wbuffer_convert`. However, the usage examples are absent.

Are there any concise examples to illustrate their usages and differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### `std::wstring_convert`

Given an `std::u32string` (a.k.a. `std::basic_string<char32_t>`) that holds UTF-32 code units in the form of `char32_t` elements, here's how to convert it to a sequence of UTF-8 code units in the form of bytes:

```
// Both <locale> and <codecvt> required

std::u32string input = U"Hello, World";

using Codecvt = std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>;
std::wstring_convert<Codecvt, char32_t> converter;

// throws std::range_error if the conversion fails
std::string result = converter.to_bytes(input);
```

Take note that a quirk of `std::wstring_convert` is that is always converts what the Standard calls a wide string (which is in fact any kind of specialization of `std::basic_string`, including `std::string`) to or from a byte string, which is a specialization of the form `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator>`.

What the source and target encodings will be depends on what code conversion facet is used -- here I am using one of the stock facets that come from `<codecvt>`. Any code conversion facet will do as long as it is Destructible, which is not the case for e.g. `std::codecvt<wchar_t>` -- it has a protected destructor.

### `std::wbuffer_convert`

Here's a hopefully compelling use case: you have an `out` object which is an instance of `std::ostream` (a.k.a `std::basic_ostream<char>`) that expects UTF-8 encoded text. So for instance `out << u8"Hello"` should work just fine. As it so happens though, you have a lot of UTF-32 encoded wide-strings (best candidate for that job would be `std::u32string`) coming from somewhere else in your program, which you need to pass to `out`. You could use `std::wstring_convert` repeatedly, but that can get old quickly.

Here's another way:

```
std::wbuffer<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> wout { out.rdbuf() };
std::u32string input = U"Hello";
wout << input;
```

That is, we can get a view of `out` that behaves as if it were an instance of `std::basic_stream<char32_t>` and that expects UTF-32 encoded text, and we didn't alter locales (that last bit being a big reason those convenience interfaces exist in the first place).

I'd like to think that `std::wbuffer_convert` is complementary to `std::wstring_convert` rather than a competitor.

<sub>As a disclaimer, because I haven't laid my hands on an implementation that supports either of those features or `<codecvt>`, the code here is completely untested :(.</sub>